# Centered family in a Boolean algebra

Tags: definition, first-order-logic

I do not understand the definition of a *centered* family in a Boolean algebra.  Here's the definition

> A family $R\subset A$ is said to be *centered*, if for every finite set $\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\subset R$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n > \mathbb{O}$.

this is from *Logic of Mathematics* by Adamowicz and Zbierski.  Part of Exercise 3.9 on page 23.  I cannot do the exercise because I don't understand the definition.

Is it saying, "For every finite set $S$, it is the case that $S\subset R$" or is it saying, "For every finite subset $S$ of $R$, all of its elements are positive"?  But in a Boolean algebra ***every*** element is greater than $\mathbb{O}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a typo.  It should instead say that the *meet* $a_1\wedge \dots\wedge a_n$ of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is greater than $0$.

Comment: No!  My bad.  I misread it.  In this book they use $\cdot$ in place of $\wedge$.  There is no comma, I wrote that when I asked the question.  I confused $\ldots$ with $\cdots$.  This makes sense! Awesome, thank you